# Rcpp: change a list item in a list of a list

Tags: c++, r, list, rcpp

Change a list item in a list of a list.

Unfortunately, I could not find an answer to my question in the forum.

Using rcpp, I want to directly change a list item in a list. I have the following approach:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(){
    Environment env = Environment::global_env();
    List outerList = env["ListR"];
    List innerList = polymeraseFlagList[0];

    outerList((1)) ) "test";                        // correctly changing inner list
    CharacterVector innerStr = innerList[1];    // correctly access to inner list element
}
```

However, I am only able to change the complete list list [i] and not a single element: `list [[i]] or list [i][j]`.

```
outerList[i][j] = "new inner list element";     // not working
outerList[[i]]  = "new inner list";             // not working
```

I can extract the inner list, but here I change only the newly created list and not the old list. It is essential for me to change the list in R Workspace directly. I could of course change the newly created list and later assign it to the old one. However, I hope that there is a more elegant solution here.

I also tried to declare the list before assigning it so that I already have a nested list that I can access as usual. Unfortunately, this did not work.

```
List outerList = List::create(Named("lst"));    // not working
```

In the end, I want the following to be possible (change the variable directly in the R Workspace):

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(){
    Environment env = Environment::global_env();
    List outerList = env["ListR"];

    CharacterVector innerStr = outerList[i][j];
    CharacterVector innerList = outerList[[i]]
    innerList[i][j] = "new String";
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me.

Many thanks :)

Comment: "List innerList = polymeraseFlagList[0];"  is "List innerList = outerList[0];"

Comment: What's this: ` outerList((1)) ) "test";`? And this `outerList[[i]]`? Please provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Also do you expect the environment to reflect the changes you make tot he list? You are copying them, not modifying the original one.

Comment: "CharacterVector" instead of "Character Vecotr". - sorry.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher example for the list:

listR = list(list()).
listR[[1]] = c(1,2,3,4,5);
ListR[[2]] = c(6,7,8,9,10);

If I changing the outerList in Rcpp like:
outerList((1)) = "test".
I get, after leaving the function test() in listR: 
listR[[1]] = 1,2,3,4,5;
ListR[[2]] = "Test";

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher by changing the outerList((i)) I directly changing the listR[i].

Comment: Maybe I understood something wrong. I thought that if I assign an Rcpp object to an R object (and not a pure cpp object, like double) I can not get an address change and thus can directly modify the R object.

Comment: Can you please [edit]  your question to remove at least the trivial typos?

Comment: @RalfStubner I tried it several times but by clicking edit i got the message "Page Not Found". I am logged in and tried it with different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some of your posted code hard to follow, but this is a fairly straightforward task, whether accessing the list from the global environment in R in a hard-coded way as you first tried, or having the list passed as a parameter; using the C++ code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(List x) {
    CharacterVector tmp = x[0];
    tmp[0] = "Z";
    x[0] = tmp;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test2() {
    Environment env = Environment::global_env();
    List x = env["ListR"];
    CharacterVector tmp = x[0];
    tmp[0] = "Y";
    x[0] = tmp;
}

/*** R
ListR <- list(a = LETTERS[1:3])
ListR
test(ListR)
ListR
test2()
ListR
*/
```

I get in R

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("modify-list.cpp")

> ListR <- list(a = LETTERS[1:3])

> ListR
$a
[1] "A" "B" "C"


> test(ListR)

> ListR
$a
[1] "Z" "B" "C"


> test2()

> ListR
$a
[1] "Y" "B" "C"
```

#### Update

This is also fairly straightforward to extend to a list within a list; using the C++ code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// For when you need to modify an element of a list within a list
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test3() {
    Environment env = Environment::global_env();
    List y = env["listR"];
    List x = y[0];
    CharacterVector tmp = x[0];
    tmp[0] = "Z";
    x[0] = tmp;
}
```

I get the following in R

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("modify-list.cpp")
listR = list(list())
listR[[1]] = list(LETTERS[1:3])
listR
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
test3()
listR
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "Z" "B" "C"
```

Comment: Many thanks duckmayr! You are right, I should have written clearer. The hard coded way is what I want. Do you have an example for a list in R which include a list. Like: listR = list(list()); listR[[1]] = c("A","B","C");

Comment: @Till It's pretty easy to extend to a list within a list; see the updates to the answer

Comment: @Till please feel free to accept and upvote the answer. That's how StackOverflow works, and there is a [tour for new users](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sure! :)